# Pipe is being closed Exception

Tags: c#, .net, pipe

Sometimes, on some machines often and on some seldom, the clients which are using my program are getting a "pipe is being closed" exception. This happens on the NamedPipeServerStream that is on .WaitForConnection(). After that, the Application totally crashes and releases a windows exception. This happens when a NamedPipeClientStream transfers information to the standalone application.

main Funktionality:
I wrote several Tools (Office Toolbars, a Service, a standalone .net Application, and a litle starter exe) that communicate together with NamedPipes. 
The Service runs a NamedPipeServerStream that is always open (in state .WaitForConnection();) and the Standalone Application has a NamedPipeServerStream too. 
The Toolbars and starter .exe communicate with the service. The Service then with the Standalone Application.

what kind of problems can release the pipe is being closed Exception?
Is it possible that the server sends information to the Standalone Application but closes the stream to early because the Standalone Application is not ready or something? on each NamedPipeClientStream i do a waitforpipedrain if pipeClient.IsConnected befor i close the pipeclient..

thanks for help

edit: Here an Example of a clientstream

```
using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient =
        new NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipename, PipeDirection.Out))
{
    // Wait for a client to connect
    try
    {                            
        pipeClient.Connect(3000);

        // send params to the form
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient))
        {
            sw.AutoFlush = true;
            sw.WriteLine(sendtext);
        }
    }
    // Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is
    // broken or disconnected.
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (sid != "")
        {
            connections.Remove(conName);
        }
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("SendText Fehler 1 " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (pipeClient.IsConnected)
        {
            pipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();
        }
        pipeClient.Close();
        pipeClient.Dispose();
    }
```

Example of an pipeserver (that runs in a seperad thread)

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer;
PipeSecurity pipe_security = CreateSystemIoPipeSecurity();
do
    string pipename = global::TOfficeCenter.Properties.Settings.Default.pipename;
    string aText = "";
    pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.In, ONE_INSTANCE, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
                                    PipeOptions.None, IN_BUF_SIZE, OUT_BUF_SIZE, pipe_security);
    try
    {
        // Verbindung zu TOfficeCenter.exe aufbauen
        try
        {
            IsWaiting = true;
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
            IsWaiting = false;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer))
            {
                string temp;
                while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    aText = aText + temp;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                if (aText == "")
                {
                    empfang(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (aText != "KillPipe")
                    {  // XML empfangen
                        XmlDocumentTC xml = new XmlDocumentTC();
                        xml.LoadXml(aText);
                        empfang(xml);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                empfang(null);
            }
        }
        catch 
{...........
}       
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {...........
    }

} while (running);

pipeServer.Close();
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not closing the pipe by accident in one of the applications?

Comment: I would guess at the client data causing an exception in the server.  Which is unhandled so that the server shuts down, producing that exception in the client.  Improve the exception logging in your server to diagnose this better, implement the AppDomain.UnhandledException event.

Comment: Didn' want to send, sorry... on the client side i close the clientstream every time i wrote something in the pipe. on the pipeserver side, after the pipeserver got some data, it restarts the pipe again.
@HansPassant: The Exception happens while the Server is at PipeServer.WaitForConnection. I dont know why the same application that has thrown the exception then totally crashes..
I will post some examples of the pipeclient and pipeserver side

Comment: Heh... `throw new PipeIsBeingClosedException();`. Good title. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that i finally found the problem..

I found out that after this code:

```
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient))
                    {
                        sw.AutoFlush = true;
                        sw.WriteLine(sendtext);
                    }
```

the pipeClient.IsConnected(); returns directly false, so that it never comes to the WaitForPipeDrain. I Now did it like that and hope that the client does not close the connection before the server is finished with reading..

```
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient))
                    {
                        sw.AutoFlush = true;
                        sw.WriteLine(sendtext);
                        pipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();
                    }
```

Do You Think that could have solved the problem? Since i did it, i never got the error on two test-machines. But the Errors anyway happened seldom..

Answer (score 0):

My use is a bit different, but I'll include the server thread in sum as it's mostly being hacked from the MSDN page at present:

[MSDN: How to Use Named Pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx)

Not sure if the "WaitForPipeToDrain()" is needed for me, but I took it from your code :)

I think the reset of the pipeServer each time is what cleaned up my IOException.

```
    int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    bool sentinel = true;

    while (sentinel)
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer =
            new NamedPipeServerStream("shapspipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1);
        // Wait for a client to connect
        pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

        Console.WriteLine("Client connected on thread[{0}].", threadId);
        try
        {
            // Read the request from the client. Once the client has
            // written to the pipe its security token will be available.

            StreamString ss = new StreamString(pipeServer);

            // Verify our identity to the connected client using a
            // string that the client anticipates.

            ss.WriteString("I am the one true server!");
            string message = ss.ReadString();

            Console.WriteLine("received from client: " + message);

            ss.WriteString("echo from server: " + message);

            Console.WriteLine("Received from client: {0} on thread[{1}] as user: {2}.",
                message, threadId, pipeServer.GetImpersonationUserName());
        }
        // Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is broken
        // or disconnected.
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
        pipeServer.Close();
    }
```